# jQuery/javascript if-statement with css values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement

I'm slightly new to the if statements and I'm working on an animation where:

If `<div id="headlights">` displays "none" in the css (which is constantly fading in and out), I want `<div id="speech-bubble-dark">` to fade in.

And when the `<div id="headlights">` displays "block" in the css, I want `<div id="speech-bubble-sun">` to fade in.

```
function bubbleTest(){
if($("#headlights").css("display") == "none" ) {
    $("#speech-bubble").fadeOut('600');
    $("#speech-bubble-sun").fadeOut('600', function(){
        $("#speech-bubble-dark").fadeIn('600');
    });

}   else{
        $("#speech-bubble").fadeOut('600');
        $("#speech-bubble-dark").fadeOut('600', function(){
            $("#speech-bubble-sun").fadeIn('600');              
        });

    }
}
```

I've tested it and the fades do not work, and dependent on the display condition being "none" or "block" it displays a different div.

What would you suggest I do?

Comment: How many times are you calling the function bubbleTest?  If only once then it will process the if block just once, and the else probably won't happen.  Perhaps you need a carefully-timed setTimeout call inside the bubbleTest function to call it repeatedly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript originally posted:

```
function bubbleTest(){
if($("#headlights").css("display") == "none" ) {
    $("#speech-bubble").fadeOut('600');
    $("#speech-bubble-sun").fadeOut('600', function(){
        $("#speech-bubble-dark").fadeIn('600');
    });

}   else{
        $("#speech-bubble").fadeOut('600');
        $("#speech-bubble-dark").fadeOut('600', function(){
            $("#speech-bubble-sun").fadeIn('600');              
        });

    }
}
bubbleTest();
```

surprisingly works as intended, here is proof:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zoNevZ

The problem must have been how I was calling the function, which I did not provide at the time (5 years ago).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this. Try it

```
function bubbleTest(){
   if(!$("#headlights").is(":visible")){//This will check for headlights is visible or not
      $("#speech-bubble").fadeOut(600);
      $("#speech-bubble-sun").fadeOut(600, function(){
        $("#speech-bubble-dark").fadeIn(600);
      });
   }
   else{
      $("#speech-bubble").fadeOut(600);
      $("#speech-bubble-dark").fadeOut(600, function(){
        $("#speech-bubble-sun").fadeIn(600);              
      });
}
```

Comment: The first bubble fades in fine, but the else-statement doesn't then fade out or fade the other in. What you've done is certainly a lot more practical than what I had any way.

Comment: @joe - Can you be lil more clear of what you want, I can edit my answer?

Comment: Can you check my edited answer? Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: I just checked your edit, and it doesn't seem to be working how I'd like it to. On the first section, the #speech-bubble-dark, does fade in, but during the animation when the #headlights are hidden, it does not fade in the next speech bubble!

Comment: @ShankarSangoli, may I ask you to have a visit at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554666/type-show-a-name-list-like-facebook-status-box/9554760#comment12110040_9554760 ? I don't know whether such a request is valid in SOF.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:

```
$("#headlights").css("display") == "none"
```

with this:

```
if (!$("#headlights").is(':visible'))
```

`:visible` is a jQuery "selector" (read the docs on them if you haven't, they're highly informative). You can use the `is()` method to do things like check to see if the visible selector is true. Likewise, you can do things like this for form elements:

```
if ($('#optInCheckbox').is(':checked'))
```

Comment: Definitely works, thank you! But my else-statement doesn't. Any ideas?