# fading divs in and out with if-statment

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement

Basically I'm trying to either fade in or out `<div id="speech-bubble-sun">` or `<div id="speech-bubble-dark">`, dependent on the visibility of an animated fading div `<div id="headlights">`. So [here is what I have so far](http://jsfiddle.net/lexbi/hWvJ4/39/).

I'm calling the if statement at different intervals throughout the function, and it does now work!

But, the if-statement ceases to work once the function has been called upon itself again (in the loop).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121144/jquery-javascript-if-statement-with-css-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "if" test is working fine.

"fadein" and "fadeout" are done asynchronously from your own code. i.e. Your own code continues to execute while the "headlights" div fades in/out.

When "fadeout" completes, the "headlights" div is set to "hidden" (not visible), but a fraction of a millisecond later it will become visible as it fades in then fades out.

So for over 99% of its time it will be visible, while for only less than 1% of the time (from the precise instant the "fadeout" completes till just before the "fadein" starts) it will be hidden, so you will almost always see the "speech-bubble-sun", rather than "speech-bubble-dark". You will not ping-pong between these two divs.

Comment: Just added a delay to the fadeIn for 5 seconds so it's hidden for longer, and it is still unresponsive. http://jsfiddle.net/lexbi/hWvJ4/44/

Comment: In your latest jsfiddle the 3 tests for "visible" will always be FALSE because of the asynchronous nature of animations. Put an "alert" at the beginning of the "bubbletest" code and you will see, or better still use Firebug under Firefox to set breakpoints and examine the properties of the DIVs. Regards

Comment: Joe, You would be better off adding and removing a class [e.g. $('#headlights').addClass('visible')] for the "headlights" div when you fadeIn and fadeOut and then testing for that class [e,g, if ($('#headlights').hasClass('visible')], rather than trying to do it by looking at the "visibility" property. Regards